# flutter Problem in vs code (Unable to Load asset)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, assets, audio-player

I'm having a problem in flutter on vs code
I imported the audioplayers
here's my pubspec.yaml

[image]

here's my homepage where I call the audio players

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
        title: Text('anghami'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.brown[200],
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    "benab",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                  ),
                  //tileColor: Colors.red,
                  leading: Icon(Icons.music_note),
                  iconColor: Colors.red,
                  onTap: () async {
                    final player = AudioPlayer();
                    await player
                        .setSource(AssetSource('assets/music/music1.mp3'));
                  },
                ),
              ),
              
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

whenever i try to play the music from the phone I get this error

[image]

P.S: the vs code has no problem in loading images or using other type of assets .

i've tried using Audiocache it doesn't work especially they deleted it in the last version ^1.1.1 ,
[enter image description here][https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9kKR.png]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you trying to load an asset in `/assets/assets/music/` folder.
My guess is that you want to load an asset in `/assets/music/` folder and it's a simple mistake.

To fix that:

```dart
// Replace the relative path of your asset below:
// assets/music/music1.mp3 -> music/music1.mp3
await player.setSource(AssetSource('music/music1.mp3'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a `assets` directory on the root of your project , then create `music` folder.

Try to play with

```dart
await player.setSource(AssetSource('music/music1.mp3'));
```

Comment: When i don't change where my files are and use your path i get this in the debug console : V/MediaPlayer(31278): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer(31278): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null

Comment: Can you try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: and whenever I change the directory and remove the assets folder i get the same error .

Comment: Can you include your assets' folder structure, the way you put the file

Comment: i'm currently using this structure because it is te only one which doesn't show me the fail to load asset error : 
anghami\assets\music 
when I use anghami\music i get the error ..

Comment: is ` anghami` your project name(root)

Comment: yes anghami is my root

Comment: try `await player.setSource(AssetSource('music/music1.mp3')); `

Comment: syntax error must use , not ; 
☺

Comment: can you show it?

Comment: Try to follow the update structure, the `AssetSource` will set `assets`

Comment: i edited the original question so i can show you my monitor

Comment: Can you include the ss of `music1.mp3` on explorer of vscode

Comment: what is the ss ?

Comment: ss means screenshot

Comment: done bro here you go 
https://ibb.co/72ZPYVY

Answer (score 0):

Just remove assets from your audio source like this:

```
await player.setSource(AssetSource('music/music1.mp3'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys the solutions here are useful , so the main problem that I had was in the path so after correction it loaded the asset in a normal way,
but instead of just loading the asset you want it to play obviously and that's guaranteed by using :

```
 **final player = AudioPlayer();**

 **await player.play(AssetSource('music/music1.mp3'));**
```

Comment: your function must be **async** since we're using here **await**